# jqgrid add image to label (index) name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm little newbie at jqgrid and I haven't "inject" it to the project, someone else did. But I got a task that I should insert image to label name instead of tekst. So I did:

```
getColModel: ->
[...]
{name:'closing', label: "<img src=\"#{url("/static/css/images/shield-icon.png")}\" title=" + i18n('ProjectList.closing') + ">", classes:'grid_col', align:'center',width:3, searchoptions:{sopt:filterOperators.date}, cellattr: ((rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) -> return "title="+"'"+rawObject.protectionTooltip+"'")}
```

But unfortunetly it end up you can see below

[image: Image Description)]

To the left we see the one that I add with original size (and I have to add it with original). On the right we see another one that I add but its 10x10 not 16x16. So where should I change something so that row will 'fit in'?

I hope image will make you understand

Comment: You can check the existing css for jqGrid row and overwrite the css to handle the width and height of particular row.

Comment: the only thing i'm able to do is setting position(imo is bad move) but it ends up in wrong shield position. The position of all this tables are relative, meaby this is an issue.